# Some checks for polymorphic field without foreign ref to other table?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Creating  polymorphic field with migration rule :

```
    $table->morphs('model');
```

I got 2 fields :

```
  `model_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `model_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
```

But seems I can not create foreign ref to other table in mysql, postgres ?

Are there some possible decision of this problem somehow in laravel ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `model_type` referees the model name, while the `model_id` store the identifier.
You can enforce foreign ref, you need to implement a different polymorphic version of laravel (I don't recommend other for polymorphic could not work properly with laravel functions). I have seen implementations where you create a bunch of nullable columns but with the foreign ref intact.

Comment: Could you please give links to such implementations ?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/polymorphism-why-should-i-violate-database-design?page=1&replyId=748370 this guy talks about it. Still do not recommend (you will be on your own), later need to do find, store, update, delete etc.